# Why am I getting multiple Observables?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm trying to get a better understanding of Observables, and am confused as to why I seem to be "spawning" multiple observables as below. For instance, if I type "a", "b", "c" into the input box, I get the following output in the console:

```
// Keyed: a
// Keyed: ab
// Keyed: ab
// Keyed: abc
// Keyed: abc
// Keyed: abc
```

but I thought the code below would only instantiate one observable, so I was expecting to get the following output:

```
// Keyed: a
// Keyed: ab
// Keyed: abc
```

Code:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { fromEvent, Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<input (keyup)="doStuff()">`
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit  {
  name = 'Angular';
  obs$: Observable<any>;

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.obs$ = fromEvent(this.el.nativeElement, "keyup")
  }

  doStuff() {
    this.obs$.subscribe(v=> console.log("Keyed: " + v.target.value))
  }
```

Doesn't `ngOnInit()` only get called once? So don't I only have one Observable? If so, why don't I get one output per keystroke?

Comment: every call to doStuff() is going to create new subscription for `this.obs$`

Comment: So the old subscription persists, and there's also a new subscription? If so, how do I "kill" the old subscription once it completes, so there's just the new subscription?

Comment: You don't need new subscription, that's the beauty of `RxJS`. You create it once and every time that event is triggered, your callback function will be called

Comment: Don't create and kill subscriptions all over, move `this.obs$.subscribe` to `ngOnInit`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because every time you trigger `keyup` event, you create a new subscription.

You can change your code to following

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<input>`
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit  {
  name = 'Angular';

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    fromEvent(this.el.nativeElement, "keyup")
           .subscribe(v=> console.log("Keyed: " + v.target.value))
  }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

every call to `doStuff()` is going to create new subscription for `this.obs$` observable.

change

```
template: `<input (keyup)="doStuff()">`
```

to

```
template: `<input>`
```

and subscribe only once inside `ngOnInit()`

Comment: I upvoted this, and consider this a great answer. Because the answer below has actual code example, I checked that as the answer, but this is equally as good. Thank you!